# ErrorException Undefined variable: item

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy haciendo una plantilla de blog y lo que quiero es mostrar el tema, título, y tiempo de lectura del post de manera que en dicha página aparezcan varias presentaciones de post de este modo. La información no la saco de ninguna bbdd sino que quiero que mediante un array aparezca "i" veces esta estructura pero me da ese error.

En el controlador tengo esto:

```
  public function blog()
{
    $elementos=[];
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        $item = (object) array(
            'tema' => 'Hello World',
            'titulo' => 'welcome',
            'tiempo' => 'welcome',
        array_push($elementos,(object) $item));
        
    }
   

return view('saasbox.blog.portadablog2', compact('elementos',));
}
```

En la vista tengo esto:

```
<div class="saasbox--blog--area blog-full section-padding-120">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row g-5">
    @foreach ($elementos as $elemento)
      <!-- Single Blog Post-->
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="card blog-card border-0 no-boxshadow rounded-0"><a class="d-block mb-4" href="blog-card.html"><img src="imgsaasbox/blog4.jpg" alt=""></a>
          <div class="post-content"><a class="d-block mb-1" href="blog-card.html">{{ $elemento['tema'] }}/a><a class="post-title d-block mb-3" href="blog-card.html">
              <h4>{{ $elemento['titulo'] }}</h4></a>
            <div class="post-meta"><span class="text-muted">{{ $elemento['time'] }}</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
       
      </div>
      @endforeach
```

Y en web.php esto:

```
Route::group(
            [
            'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale()
            ],
            function()
                {
                Route::get('/blog2', 'BlogController2@blog')->name('blog/portadablog2');
                });
```

Me da el fallo de arriba y no veo cómo solucionarlo.
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Quieres meter a `$item` dentro de sí mismo en el `array_push`
?

Comment: Es que si lo quito del array push me salta otro error "Undefined variable: title" y no tengo nada que se llame "title"

Comment: No me refiero a que quites el `array_push`, sino que el `array_push` está dentro del array que intentas crear y que se llama `$item`, no sé si lo percibes ¿? El `array_push` debería estar fuera del array... Por otra parte, una de las llaves se llamaría `tiempo`, por lo que aquí tendrás un *Undefined index*: `$elemento['time']`, deberías poner `$elemento['tiempo']`

Comment: Prueba así: `$item = (object) array('tema' => 'Hello World', 'titulo' => 'welcome', 'tiempo' => 'welcome');`  OBSERVA que el array se cierra con `)` en `welcome`. Y ahora pones esto, fuera del array: **`array_push($elementos,(object) $item));`**

Comment: Podrías hacerlo también así, más simple: **`$elementos[] = (object) array('tema' => 'Hello World', 'titulo' => 'welcome', 'tiempo' => 'welcome');`** y QUITAS el `array_push`. Ahí te meterá el objeto dentro de `$elementos` directamente. Visto eso, digamos que es un código sin sentido, porque estás guardando siempre las mismas cosas, no hay nada diferente que se guarde dentro de ese array, son siempre datos fijos, ¿a qué se debe eso?

Comment: He probado lo que comentas de sacar el array push del array pero salta otro error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array (View: posts2.blade.php)

Comment: No sé qué código final estás implementando. Si haces esto: `$elementos[] = (object) array('tema' => 'Hello World', 'titulo' => 'welcome', 'tiempo' => 'welcome');` y eliminas la línea del `array_push`  te creará un array de objetos en `$elementos` directamente.

Comment: Y, en la vista, tienes que modificar el código, poniéndolo así: `<div class="post-meta"><span class="text-muted">{{ $elemento->tiempo }}</span></div>` Los cambios son dos: 1º. Usarías la notación de objeto que `$objeto->propiedad`, no la notación de array que es `$array["indice"]`; 2º. Usas el nombre de la propiedad, que es `tiempo`, no `time`, porque la propiedad que creas dentro del `for` se llama `tiempo`

Comment: Gracias! Ahora sí puedo verlo. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! Un saludo.

Comment: Dime si con eso se ha resuelto el problema para agregar una respuesta.

Comment: En cierto modo, así funcionaba pero yo quería utilizar el bucle for para que me lo sacara 12 veces en la pantalla y al final puse el array push de este modo y funcionó: for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++){
        array_push($elementos,(object) $item);

Comment: Pues eso es lo mismo que ponerlo así, dentro del bucle: `$elementos[] = (object) array('tema' => 'Hello World', 'titulo' => 'welcome', 'tiempo' => 'welcome');`Incluso esta forma es más rápida que con `array_push`, según el Manual de PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Ese error lo único que te dice es que no tienes inicializado tu array **$item** igual que como lo haces con **$elementos**.